# detect value of $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']

Tags: php

I have two web application on two apache.and call it

```
192.168.0.20:8082       and  192.168.0.20:8088     (local) or 
http://automation:8082  and  http://automation:8088(local) or
80.191.155.144:8082     and  80.191.155.144:8088   (public).
```

Now i want  redirect from application1 to application2 or application2 to appication1.
for example redirect from

```
http://automation:8082/showList.php to http://automation:8088/detailList.php 
192.168.0.20:8082/showList.php      to 192.168.0.20:8088/detailList.php 
80.191.155.144:8082/showList.php    to 80.191.155.144:8088/detailList.php
```

How can find url has local ip(192.168.0.20) or (automation) or public(80.191.155.141)? and redirect base on.
i use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but this in `http://automation` return ip6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`

```
$host=explode(':',$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])[0];
```

redirect from `$host:8082/showList.php` to `$host:8088/detailList.php`

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_Host']` contains the string that was specified in the HTTP `Host:` header. This normally contains the hostname portion of the URL the client used to connect.

Performing the redirect using the Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module might be less complex then sending a 302 in each PHP script.